# How do you prevent updates to the ownerField of an AWS Amplify GraphQL API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amplifyjs, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I created a GraphQL API using AWS' Amplify. In the schema, I have a Comment model that looks like this:

```
type Comment
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }, { allow: private, operations: [read] }, { allow: public, operations: [read] }])
  @model
  @key(name: "byAuthor", fields: ["authorID"])
  @key(name: "byPost", fields: ["postID"]) {
  content: String!
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
  id: ID!
  owner: String
  postID: ID!
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime!
}
```

This gives the owner permission to create, read, update, and delete, and restricts unauthenticated/authenticated-non-owner users to read-only. This works as expected; however, the owner can update the ownerField's value, essentially attributing the comment to another user...which is a no-no. To prevent this, I tried using field-level permissions (see below); however, that doesn't appear to be stopping the update.

```
...
owner: String @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [ create ]}])
...
```

Is there something I'm missing? Any help is much appreciated--thank you!

Comment: I've tried setting the top-level auth rules to only allow create, read, and delete operations for the owner and changing the field-level auth on the content field to update to see if the inverse would work, and I'm still able to update the owner field.

Answer (score 6):

You're very close. Using a field-level `@auth` directive, you want to explicitly grant the owner the ability to `create` and `read` and explicitly deny the world the ability to `update` and `delete`. It might look something like:

```
type Todo
    @model
    @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "author" }]) {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    author: String
        @auth(
            rules: [
                { allow: groups, groups: ["FORBIDDEN"], operations: [update, delete] }
                { allow: owner, ownerField: "author", operations: [create, read] }
            ]
        )
}
```

Here, the "FORBIDDEN" group is a non-existent group. Its name can be anything so long as you do not plan to actually create a group by that name in the future. Because no user will ever have the "FORBIDDEN" group claim, any/all `update` or `delete` operations on the field will fail.